# get access to a module class by its name in Vue using vue-property-decorator

Tags: vue.js, vue-property-decorator

when we use vue-property-decorator and define the module by:

```
export default class ModuleName extends Vue {
   ...
}
```

and embed multi modules in app can we get access to a specific one of these modules by addressing the name of the module?
I mean considering these scheme can I call and run a function belongs to Module_C from Module_A?

```
... base
     |
     .... Module_A
     |
     .... Module_B
            |
            .... Module_C
```

I mean something like this:

In Module_A : `Vue.Module_C.someFunctionBelongsToModuleC();`

p.s. I am totally aware of Bus technique, $emit, $parent, ...
I want to know if the ModuleName itself has any merit here or not?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say "Module", you're referring to Components in Vue. Since using the class syntax for components results in those components being object instances, you can access any members including functions using [refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs). So, Module_A could invoke functions on Module_B, and Module_B invoke functions on Module_C. To access members of Module_C from Module_A, Module_B would need to expose those through a member of its own.

That said, this isn't a good idea :). Passing props down the chain is preferred whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for Explanation, Yeah I mean Component by Module, 
Let's clear it a bit more, consider this as an example: I have multi frame app, I want by pressing a button in A, call `this.navigateBack()` in C! and I am asking if that ModuleName comes in handy?
I mean can I use this name as a shortcut, and help me to do not passing down props, while when the app gets very big, passing prop would be not a wise option, and using bus technique would be rational option, but I am asking if that `export default class ModuleName` could be used as a shortcut?

Comment: If you find you need to control C directly from A, the best way I know is to pass C from A to B via a slot. Then A can get a ref to C and invoke functions.

Comment: as you said we can use refs, so I am asking is there any other method that I can reach the Component by its name not chaining the refs.

Comment: There is the $children property on the Vue instance, which you could try to traverse. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children